# I have a reset button for reset display timer and value of number picker but it's not reset the vaule of number picker. How can I fix it?

Tags: flutter, dart, reset, numberpicker

```
Widget hourPicker() {
return Column(
  children: <Widget>[
    Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 5.0),
      child: Text(
        "HH",
        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
      ),
    ),
    NumberPicker.integer(
        // initialValue: initHour,
        initialValue: hour,
        minValue: 0,
        maxValue: 23,
        onChanged: (val) {
          setState(() {
            if (reset != reset) {
              val = 12;
            } else {
              hour = val;
            }
          });
        })
  ],
);
```

}`

****This is a number picker and I want to reset Val when I press on reset button
How to write a function to reset it but not use Navigator***

Answer (score 0):

a good way will be to use a function that triggers when you press reset button and there you can change the value of the hour variable inside setState because according to your code it will only perform check if u perform any action on the number picker and on changed is triggered

```dart
resetPicker(){
  setState((){
    hour= 12;
  });
}
```

add code to trigger the reset function your button like bellow

```dart
RaisedButton(
  child: Text('Reset'),
  onPressed: ()  {resetPicker();}
)
```

you also have to make changes to on changed like below

```dart
NumberPicker.integer(
        initialValue: hour,
        minValue: 0,
        maxValue: 23,
        onChanged: (val) {
          setState(() {
            hour = val;
          });
        })
```

Comment: The value on the Number picker not changes

Comment: it will be good if u can provide the code of whole widget and not just the number picker part that will help me to understand the issue a bit batter

Comment: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1JobMZa6vFZg8HkEGEbQ5OyzdcKhs7nKF?usp=sharing